# An example of Mellin transform asymptotics

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions, asymptotics, integral-transforms

Let $$F(x) = \sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{1}{1+k^2x^2}$$ and its Mellin transform
$$F(s) = \frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\zeta(s)}{\sin{\frac{\pi}{2}s}}, \space\space  where  \space\space (1<Re(s)<2)$$
And then, its asymptotics are
$$F(x)_{x\to0+} \approx \frac{\pi}{2x}-\frac{1}{2}+O(x^M)\space (M\gt0),\space and \space\space F(x)_{x\to\infty} \approx \frac{\pi^2}{6x^2}-\frac{\pi^4}{90x^4}+\space...$$

Now I understand the poles of $F(s)$ are $0,1,2,4,6,8...$,

and $0,1 $ are related to $F(x)_{x\to0+}$ and $2,4,6,8...$ to $F(x)_{x\to\infty}$ , because of $(1<Re(s)<2)$, the right/left plane.

Q1) How can I find these 4 coefficients?

(I tried a typical partial fraction method, and managed to get only $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$)

(Also I tried to use residue theorem, but the contour integral was so frustrating at poles 0,1)

Q2) I thought the poles should be in the region $(1<Re(s)<2)$ for asymptotics. But it doesn't look like they should necessarily from the above-mentioned example. What's the difference between in and out of the region? What does it mean for asymptotics?

Comment: The second one is simple since, without using Mellin transform $$F(x) = \sum_{k= 1^\infty }\frac{1}{1+k^2x^2}=\frac{\pi  \coth \left(\frac{\pi }{x}\right)}{2 x}-\frac{1}{2}$$ Just use Taylor series (it works)

Comment: Use the know values of $\zeta(2n)$ in terms of Bernoulli numbers and powers of $\pi$.

Comment: @Gary / Thank you. I should've studied Riemann zeta func more in the first place. :)

Comment: @Claude Leibovici / Thank you for your answer. But, I am studying Mellin transform, so I needed to know how to get it from the poles of Mellin transform func.